# Gradle - Intellij modules workspace

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to have different modules in Intellij depends on my current working environment?

E.g.
Workspace:

- Module A - Android App
- Module B - Android Lib
- Module C - Acceptance Tests
- Module D - Feature Tests
- Module E - Android Test App for libs

Configuration 1 - working on app and lib

- Module A
- Module B

Configuration 2 - working on tester app

- Module A
- Module B
- Module E

Configuration 3 - tests

- all modules

I'm using `gradle` building tool and I store my modules in `settings.gradle`. 
I would be appreciate to be able to manipulate the list of modules in `settings.gradle` file from the `Intellij` however it could be some better way for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days looking into different solutions I finally found the way how to achieve it.

[image]

There is an option in *Gradle project tool* than gives you the opportunity to exclude not required modules. **Select Project Data To Import** lets you do the magic in **IntelliJ**.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (that I know of) to do this to create new blank IntelliJ projects for each configuration and then import the modules in which you are interested into each project.

EDIT: A second way that might work for you is to use the favourites. Open up the favourites windows and add 3 new favourites lists, one for each set up. Then go to a module in the project view and select "add to favourites" and select the relevant list. Repeat this for each module and list.

Again it's not quite what you want but might be good enough.

Comment: I understand the first way but the second not really. I've added my modules to three separate favorites `app`, `tester`, `tests` but don't really know what to do next with it. There is no option to jump from one list to another - means import only that modules stored in e.g. `app` list.